# A software to manage audios in the same interface

Tags: audio

I would like a software that allows me to set what audios I want and to manage their volume all on the same interface and that works on Windows.

I can manage audios and play more than one at the same time with any basic media player, but have to change between windows often is really boring.

Comment: By audios do you mean audio files? Are you just trying to play multiple files from one UI window?

Comment: On most audio editors you can play/edit multiple tracks and export each of them, but not while exporting. For example [Ardour](https://ardour.org/) on Linux for wave files. Audacity is cross platform and Fruity Loops is for music makers. Did you search for "audio editing software"?

Answer (score 1):

Most dj programs allow you to play and add more than one deck. For example [Tactile12000](http://www.tactile12000.com/download/), [Mixxx](https://mixxx.org/) or [VirtualDJ](http://www.virtualdj.com/). Please scan Tactile12000 before downloading.

[image: VirtualDJ screenshot]

I'd use Winamp and play only one song (when something happens) by disabling jump to next song / shuffle and repeat. You reminded me something.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i get the answer correctly...
In case i got it wrong, clarify your question and add further information what you want to accomplish or what problem in detail you want to solve...

If you are looking for an alternate sound mixer bar for the windows built in one, check out this site:
https://www.windowschimp.com/audio-mixer-windows-10/

Equalizer APO is a freeware tool...
https://equalizerapo.com
check out their page for further details.

I used that tool for:
You can map channels and apply an equalizer, or some more advanced audio filters...
Handy if you want to:

- adapt frequencys, like reduce the bass in the music, or any other frequency bandwidth, handy if neighbors keep complaining about that bass sound during night hours...
- map channels, if you are using a surround sound system, you can map Left/Right channel to all other surround channels, like center, sub-woofer, etc... handy if your mp3 player does not recognize that you use a surround system and only sends audio signal to left/right channel
- have a setting for different output devices, like when you are using a surround system parallel to a headset... adapt mapping and equalizer independent of each device

Comment: I will check the program later, but answering what you asked, I would like a program that allows me to reproduce some audios from my choice all on the same interface, without having to swap between windows. Also, a function to reproduce two or more audios at the same time and increase/decrease each volume individually would be good too.

Comment: @Mycroft you mean like grouping at least 2 applications to control their volume with one slider or a set of key-buttos? I dont get what you mean by "allows me to reproduce some audios"

Comment: I did not test your recommendation yet, but I just want to play some musics on the same interface. My wish is that I don't have to control a lot of interfaces and have to change between this windows.